# Replace words in an RTF document with PHP

Tags: php, rtf

I need to replace a particular word in an RTF document by another word. I used the following code without success, because afterwards the RTF file is corrupt:

```
$rtf= file_get_contents('document.rtf');
$rtf = str_replace('[word]', 'example', $rtf);
file_put_contents('document.rtf', $rtf);
```

Any ideas or library that can help me? I know the library 'PHPRtfLite', but it seems only serve to create RTF documents, not to modify.

Comment: Here's a link to an answer on how to parse RTF with regex -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856177/research-and-replace-word-rtf. Do you have any more info for us on why the file is corruped? Error messages?

Comment: Speak coding issues. Let me open it but it shows me the content with strange characters and many more pages than the original file.